# Check in JS whether a CSS property is supported?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to check whether the CSS property `pointer-events` ([see documentation](http://www.webkit.org/specs/PointerEventsProperty.html)) is supported by the user's browser.

Currently, for example, it's not supported by Opera and I believe some versions of IE.

I'd like to run a check in JavaScript and display appropriate bits of HTML depending on whether or not it's supported.

Is there a better way to do this than checking the user-agent string?

Comment: Typically you check what the user agent is and from that you know what is or is not supported.

Comment: @Endophage: Typically, you don't do that. [Feature detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) is the superior approach. Though in the case of `pointer-events`, there is no reliable test.

Comment: @thirtydot feature detection is fine if there are only a couple of interesting things you want to do.  If you have a lot of features to detect, say everything in Modernizer, it's inefficient.

Comment: @Endophage: I'm not sure what you're saying. Modernizr extensively uses feature detection - I don't think it even *looks at* the user agent.

Comment: @thirtydot I agree, what I'm saying is, it's inefficient and painful to read code if you had to write a check for every feature using modernizer vs. just checking user agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
if ("pointer-events" in document.body.style)
```

or

```
if ("pointerEvents" in document.body.style)
```

should be adequate in the case of SVG content.

Comment: This [evaluates to true](http://jsfiddle.net/M27PT/) yet [does not work as intended](http://jsfiddle.net/7TvVY/10/) in IE9.

Comment: @art that's probably because [IE9 didn't extend this SVG property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972269(v=vs.85).aspx) to HTML content.

Comment: Looks like it's the other way around in Firefox: your statement returns false, yet the CSS works as intended.

Comment: Oh, my bad - didn't see the edit. The second variant correctly returned true on Firefox.

Comment: Accepting as true for general case, but specifically does not apply for `pointer-events` as an HTML property (rather than SVG) - @Knu, could you maybe update your answer to reflect that, in case other people are confused by it in the future?

Comment: @Richard NP if you have to use one choose the second variant. I wonder why webkit browsers support the first one.

Answer (score 6):

for non-SVG content this script should work:
 
https://github.com/ausi/Feature-detection-technique-for-pointer-events

You can also use it without Modernizr:

```
var pointerEventsSupported = (function(){
    var element = document.createElement('x'),
        documentElement = document.documentElement,
        getComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle,
        supports;
    if(!('pointerEvents' in element.style)){
        return false;
    }
    element.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    element.style.pointerEvents = 'x';
    documentElement.appendChild(element);
    supports = getComputedStyle && 
        getComputedStyle(element, '').pointerEvents === 'auto';
    documentElement.removeChild(element);
    return !!supports;
})();
if(pointerEventsSupported){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @SerjSagan It is now also included in the Modernizr non-core detects. You can go to http://modernizr.com/download/ and activate css-pointerevents in the non-core detects if you want to use Modernizr.

Answer (score 2):

The following evaluates to true in both IE 9 and Firefox:

```
if ('pointerEvents' in document.documentElement.style)
```

Comment: And in Opera, which definitely doesn't support it as an HTML property, so I'm afraid that isn't going to work.

Comment: this is not an answer, but it's true